# Scan barcodes in NativeScript with AVFoundation (ios)

Tags: ios, angular, avfoundation, nativescript

I try to implement a barcode scanner in NativeScript with angular.
I am able to display the video layer but unfortunately I am stuck to handle the barcode is scanned event. The

I think the main problem is that the setMetadataObjectsDelegateQueue doesnt work as I expected. That means in the function captureOutputDidOutputMetadataObjectsFromConnection is never called.

In my template.html I got a Placeholder which will be replaced by the creatingView Template.

Am I on the right track or did I miss something. Unfortunately I can't use the nativescript-barcodescanner plugin, because I want to display the scanner inside of an existing layout.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {ios} from "application";

   class BarcodeDelegate implements AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    captureOutputDidOutputMetadataObjectsFromConnection(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput, metadataObjects: NSArray<any>, connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        console.log('test');
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: "ns-s",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./test.component.html",
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    public init: boolean = false;

    public device: AVCaptureDevice;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.init = true;
    }

    creatingView(args) {

        let session = new AVCaptureSession();
        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720;

        // Adding capture device
        this.device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo);
        let input = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDeviceError(this.device, null);

        if (!input) {
            throw new Error("Error trying to open camera.");
        }

        session.addInput(input);

        // Layer for outputing AV Stuff
        let videoLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.layerWithSession(session);
        videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

        let metadataOutput = new AVCaptureMetadataOutput();

        if (session.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {

            session.addOutput(metadataOutput);

            try {

                let delegate = new BarcodeDelegate();

                // mainQueue var is to get dispatch_get_main_queue
                let mainQueue = (function() {
                    let runloop = CFRunLoopGetMain();
                    return function(func) {
                        CFRunLoopPerformBlock(runloop, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, func);
                        CFRunLoopWakeUp(runloop);
                    }
                }());
                    metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegateQueue(delegate, mainQueue);
                    metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode,AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
                           AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code
                    ];

            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }

        } else {
            console.log('error')
        }
        session.startRunning();

        let view = UIView.alloc().initWithFrame({ origin: { x: 0, y: 0 }, size: { width: 400, height: 200 } });
        videoLayer.frame = view.bounds;
        view.layer.addSublayer(videoLayer);
        args.view = view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hans, were you able to achieve any further progress? I am currently at the same situation as you.

Comment: Hi David, it's been a while since I've been working on this subject. I didnt't manage it to solve the problem by using the AVFoundation library directly. I decided to use the CocoaPod of https://github.com/mikebuss/MTBBarcodeScanner and it works like a charm.

Comment: Hey Hans, thanks for your reply and the link! Do you have a tip for the following problem: I display the demanded view instance via a dynamically generated Page instance with a StackLayout inside and pass the MTBBarcodeScanner the ios property of the StackLayout instance. First time the view is visited, everything works. Subsequent times the view is opened, the view is empty and the camera picture is not displayed any more. Thank you very much.